# when i'm using vuelidate library in quasar 2 get this error

Tags: quasar, vuelidate

Vue is undefined.
client-entry.js?2f39:103 [Quasar] boot error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined.

this is my boot file code.

```
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
import Vue from 'vue'
export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.use(Vuelidate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quasar 2 uses vue3.

```js
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.use(Vuelidate);
});
```

Now, this answer assumes Vuelidate supports Vue3. If it doesn't this won't work.

Comment: yes, i have tried this one too, then it give reference error where i'm using vuelidate for validations.
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/

Comment: Thanks Trent, problem solved with this referred docs.